# Filter listView from ItemAdapter

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

Im trying to filter my listView. However, when i type a letter in the EditText my listView becomes empty. Log.d shows that my m_adapter has 0 counts.

I have googled allot but not seen any solution that works for me.

ItemAdapter :

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

static ArrayList<Item> objects;

public ItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Item> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.objects = objects;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phonenumber_item, null);
    }

    Item i = objects.get(position);

    if (i != null) {

        TextView ttd = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptextdata);
        TextView btd = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desctext);           

        if (ttd != null){
            ttd.setText(i.getName());
        }

        if (btd != null){
            btd.setText(i.getDetails());
        }
    }
    return v;
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_list, container, false);
    inputSearch = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    m_adapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.phonenumber_item, m_parts);
    setListAdapter(m_adapter);

    viewParts = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(null, viewParts);
    thread.start();

    return rootView;
}

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {            

        m_parts.add(new Item("Phonenumber 1", "xxx-xxxxxx"));            
        m_parts.add(new Item("Phonenumber 2", "xxx-xxxxxx"));

        m_adapter = new ItemAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.phonenumber_item, m_parts);

         setListAdapter(m_adapter);

        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

                m_adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                Log.d("Debug", "Count: " + m_adaper.getCount());

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                          int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Just a side tip for code improvement: you're creating new adapter twice and setting this adapter to `ListView` twice, don't do it so. instead create once in `onCreateView()` add new items to your array whenever needed and then call `adapter. notifyDataSetChanged()` It'll reflect new data in `ListView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing it a bit different. Here is the code.
Credits goes to this github:
https://github.com/ihrupin/samples/tree/master/android/Filter_ListView_Sample_Custom_Objects/src/com/hrupin/sample/filterlist

PhonenumberSearchNumbers.java

```
public class PhonenumberSearchNumbers {

public static List<PhonenumberSearchItem> getItems() {
    List<PhonenumberSearchItem> m_parts = new ArrayList<PhonenumberSearchItem>();
    m_parts.add(new PhonenumberSearchItem("Number 1", "xxx-xxxxx"));
    m_parts.add(new PhonenumberSearchItem("Number 2", "xxx-xxxxx"));
    m_parts.add(new PhonenumberSearchItem("Number 3", "xxx-xxxxx"));
   }
}
```

PhonenumberSearchAdapter.java

```
public class PhonenumberSearchAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PhonenumberSearchItem> {
private LayoutInflater vi;
private static int mResource = R.layout.search_item;

public PhonenumberSearchAdapter(Activity activity, final List<PhonenumberSearchItem> items) {
    super(activity, mResource, items);
    vi = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView textViewName;
    private TextView textViewNumber;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        this.textViewName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptextdata);
        this.textViewNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.desctext);
    }
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = vi.inflate(mResource, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final PhonenumberSearchItem item = getItem(position);
    if (item != null) {
        holder.textViewName.setText(Html.fromHtml(item.getName()));
        holder.textViewNumber.setText(Html.fromHtml(item.getNumber()));
    }
    return convertView;
  }
}
```

PhonenumberSearchItem.java

```
public class PhonenumberSearchItem {

private String name;
private String number;

public PhonenumberSearchItem(String name, String number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.name;
   }
}
```

MainFragment.java

```
public class PhonenumberAllaFragment extends ListFragment implements TextWatcher {

private EditText inputSearch;
private static List<PhonenumberSearchItem> numbers = PhonenumberSearchNumbers.getItems();
private EditText editTextFilter;
private PhonenumberSearchAdapter adapter;
```

.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_list, container, false);

    editTextFilter = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    editTextFilter.addTextChangedListener(this);

    adapter = new PhonenumberSearchAdapter(getActivity(), numbers);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        PhonenumberSearchItem g = adapter.getItem(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + g.getNumber()));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

.

```
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
```